# SaaS Multitenant Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, saas

i just arrived on this architecture, am doing a lot of research and i understood how it work in general but it's all theorical.

I decided to separate each step for the development of this architecture to start implementing so i can understand better these steps.

The first that i wanted to learn was the tenant provisioning, i wanted to apply it on AWS to mirror a production software example.

So, starting on that the common AWS service that i see most people using is AWS Cognito, but it's not clear in my mind the steps of the implementation, like how should i get the tenant data to onboard him in my app? Assuming it's tier based.

Should i have one database to store all tenants data separate from the application database?

I want to use microservices on this one because i think is better to onboard the tenant with different tiers and much more benefits.

Which AWS services should i use to make this process work? I'm not really asking about the implementation itself but a path to understand which services to use and how it connects with each other.

I hope i was clear about my doubts, english is not my mother tongue, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in the right direction. However, there are decisions you need to make before diving into any saas service stack. I would start with

1. Planning my infrastructure - how many tenants/group.
2. the kind of tenant onboarding system you want
3. How will tenants onboard their users and manage authorization/authentication
4. Multitenant architecture, which needs to account for several things at the least like - DB model, shared vs isolated, data privacy, design keeping in mind industry data security standards
5. what will be your tenant deployment model. Remember one of the disadvantages of multitenancy is also slow time to market.
6. Your API stack needs to account for which apis needs to be multitenant and which are generic product offerings.
7. operational tool to monitor app health, client analytics.
8. how will you meter and bill the client and other non-functional decisions.

AWS offers good documentation to get started here : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/building-a-multi-tenant-saas-solution-using-aws-serverless-services/